# VBA - iterating over range of data cells in excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm trying to write an INSERT statement for a SQL database. I'm gathering the data from Excel cells using VBA

I already gathered the column names in a String.

Here's how I gather the data and the output in the locals window.

```
 data_vals = Sheets("Main").Range("A2", "C3")
```

[image: data_vals in debug view]

Since I'm writing an INSERT statement, I need to iterate through each row, one at a time. The final insert statement should look like:

strSQL = "INSERT INTO " & tbl_name & " ( " & column_vals & ") VALUES " & value_string

value_string should be = "(row1cell1, row1cell2, row1cell3), (row2cell1, row2cell2, row2cell3)"

**I don't need to know how to create the entire string. Knowing how I can make a double for loop that iterates through the rows, then the cells in each row would be enough. I'm pretty new to VBA.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could:

- loop through `Rows` ranges of your `Range`
- use `Value` property on each row range to get an array of its values
- use Join() function to concatenate those values
- use `&` operator and add some more characters you need

as follows:

```
    Dim row As Range
    Dim value_string As String
    For Each row In Sheets("Main").Range("A2", "C3").Rows
        value_string = value_string & "(" & Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(row.Value)), ",") & "),"
    Next
    value_string = Left(value_string, Len(value_string) - 1) ' get the last "," off your string
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, but I finally got the chance to test this. Worked perfectly, thanks.